# Adding a new line to a wrapping text field in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I am working on an OS X application in Xcode and I need to add a new line to a wrapping text field with code, but I've looked everywhere and even experimented some myself but I haven't been able to figure it out. I know when adding text to a wrapping text field that the text field will automatically add a new line when you've run out of space on the first line, but I want to create a new line in my text field with code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "completely new line"? Do you mean a line break? Have you tried `"\n"`? Please show some code and screenshots of the problem.

Comment: @jtbandes Yes, line break, I'm not totally familiar with all these coding terms.

Comment: I'm also not very good with words. But anyway, the "\n" command worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A newline character can be written `\n` in a string, e.g. `"\n"`.